# How to remove the start script error after executing 'npm start' for Reactjs App

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I started making a project in Reactjs and i am watching a tutorial from Youtube. After creating my project using "npx create-react-app", when i try to execute "npm start" it shows a bunch of errors:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! covid-19-tracker@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the covid-19-tracker@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\VIVIDH\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-09-10T05_26_49_684Z-debug.log
```

npm -v = 6.14.8
node -v 14.4.0
I have tried most of the methods but it still isn't working. Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "covid-19-tracker",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "description": "This project was bootstrapped with [Create React App](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app).",
  "main": "index.js",
  "devDependencies": {},
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/Vividh25/covid-19-tracker.git"
  },
  "author": "Vividh Bhardwaj",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/Vividh25/covid-19-tracker/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/Vividh25/covid-19-tracker#readme"
}
```

Debug.log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\VIVIDH\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.8
3 info using node@v14.4.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle covid-19-tracker@0.1.0~prestart: covid-19-tracker@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle covid-19-tracker@0.1.0~start: covid-19-tracker@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle covid-19-tracker@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle covid-19-tracker@0.1.0~start: PATH: C:\Users\VIVIDH\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\VIVIDH\desktop\Projects\covid-19-tracker\node_modules\.bin;C:\Python38\Scripts\;C:\Python38\;C:\Windows\System32;D:\src\flutter\bin;C:\src\Git\cmd;C:\src\Git\cmd\git.exe;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Windows\System32\ variable;"C:\Users\VIVIDH\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\src\Git\cmd\git.exe;C:\src\Git\cmd";D:\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\VIVIDH\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle covid-19-tracker@0.1.0~start: CWD: C:\Users\VIVIDH\desktop\Projects\covid-19-tracker
10 silly lifecycle covid-19-tracker@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'react-scripts start' ]
11 silly lifecycle covid-19-tracker@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle covid-19-tracker@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: covid-19-tracker@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\VIVIDH\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\VIVIDH\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1051:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:287:5)
14 verbose pkgid covid-19-tracker@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\VIVIDH\desktop\Projects\covid-19-tracker
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\VIVIDH\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v14.4.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.8
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error covid-19-tracker@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the covid-19-tracker@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Please help me.

Comment: can you show the logs in the file what it says

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem of `system variable path`.

DO this.

Go to > Control Panel\System and Security\System\Advance system setting\Enviroment variable and `set system variables path C:\Windows\System32\ variable` and restart.

Comment: Try to remove node_modules + package-lock.json and then run npm i try this

Comment: yup did that too. I even added npm cache clean --force. Sill it didnt work

Comment: post your debug.log

Comment: ummm how do I access that? I'm sorry I'm still new to this.

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/generating-and-locating-npm-debug-log-files#:~:text=You%20can%20find%20the%20npm,To%20find%20your%20.

Comment: I added the debug log please check

Comment: this is my last arsenal for you 
npm install create-react-app -g
cd you project folder
delete node_modules folder
npm install && npm start
run this also npx start so that it checks the PATH and local project binaries for executable.

Comment: if it helped you in any way,do upvote it so that it may help someone else :)

Comment: hey man, I tried it but it didn't work. However I have fixed by just using yarn instead of npm. Thanks for you contribution and help anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're facing the same problem and have tried everything and if it still isn't working then try running the project through yarn. You can install yarn from chocolatey which comes pre-installed when you download nodejs. Here's what you type on cmd :

```
choco install yarn
```

After installation:

```
yarn init
```

To start project:

```
yarn create react-app <your project name>
cd <your project name>
yarn start
```

This worked for me, and hope it does for you :)